# How to Blank Date value in Date formula field?

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field, date, contains

This field is to display the "date" value when this Opportunity's Stage value contains "Closed ". and at the same time Opportunity's Stage value not contains Closed means this field needs to be empty/blank.
Here Opportunity object Stage field datatype is picklist

```
IF((CONTAINS(TEXT(StageName),"closed")),NULL,Today())
```

Here am getting date value. but when Opportunity's Stage value not contains "Closed" means date field is not empty

Comment: Are you trying to create a field to hold the closed date? If yes then you can not use the formula field, you need to have another date field updated with workflow field update or process builder.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question so I don't know if you managed to fix it but you just need to change Null and Today() in your formula :

```
IF((CONTAINS(TEXT(StageName),"closed")),Today(),NULL)
```